# jQuery trouble registering 2 keyevent listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I want to be able to listen to multiple button presses, like so:

```
$("#body").keypress(function(event) {

        if (event.which == 49) { //1
         //do something
        }
        if (event.which == 68) { //d 
             //do something else
        }

});
```

But I'm not able to intercept the "d" keypress. Any advice?

Cheers

Comment: You want to respond differently to 49 and 68?

Comment: the `.which` for `"d"` is `100` when using `keypress`. `68` is when you use `keyup`.

Comment: yeah, I'll be calling function1() for 49 and function2() for 68

Comment: @Esailija - you fixed it, thanks mate

Comment: @YoungMoney actually that's wrong, keypress gives me different key values depending on whether I'm using capslock or not. Anyways, keyup is more robust, you should use it anyway :P

Comment: wait, so replace keypress with keyup? Also, to be sure, where can I find the proper charts for each char?

Comment: @YoungMoney You can see the char by alerting/logging e.which.

Comment: @YoungMoney `$(document).bind("keyup", function(e){console.log(e.which);});` and smash your keyboard while looking at console

Comment: Keypress gives you character codes while keyup/keydown gives you key code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a switch statement, permitting 100 (lowercase 'd') to fall through to 68 (uppercase 'D'):

```
$("#foo").on("keypress", function(e){
    switch( e.which ) {
        case 49 :
          alert( "You pressed a 1" );
          break;
        case 100:
        case 68 :
          alert( "You pressed a 'd'" );
    }
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/CJKUh/